# gstreamer from RTSP stream, change resolution

Tags: raspberry-pi, gstreamer, motion-detection, gst-launch-1.0

I have a Raspberry Pi zero running `v4l2rtspserver` and transmitting an RTSP stream with H264-encoded 1640x1232 frames. 
I'd like `gst-launch-1.0` to connect to it, change its resolution, and dump it somewhere.

Since I can't seem to get it right and since my `history | grep gst-launch | wc -l` marks over 500, I thought I'd beg for help.

For those who are wondering this is my problem: Raspberrypi Zero is too slow to run MotionEyeOS and so I'd like to optimize motion-detection by running `motion` on a scaled-down video stream (160x120, from a pipe or a loopback device) while retaining a full-scale video stream (via RTSP preferably, but also anything else would be ok). 
In other words, I'm trying to split the output from the camera in 2 streams and change one stream's resolution.

Any other setup to achieve this (I've tried a few: `v4l2loopback`, `ffmpeg` + `ffserver`, `mjpeg_streamer` etc.) would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found it. So...assuming you have `v4l2rtspserver` running with the default params, the `gstreamer 1.0` pipeline to resize the video on the fly is:

`gst-launch-1.0 -e rtspsrc location="rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/unicast" ! capsfilter caps="application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, payload=(int)96, encoding-name=(string)H264" ! queue ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! queue ! videoconvert ! videoscale ! video/x-raw,width=160,height=120 ! avenc_h264_omx ! h264parse ! matroskamux !  filesink location=./video.mkv`